# Firebase Firestore doesn't update UI after deletion SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to delete an object from my Firestore database through SwiftUI and the data deletes successfully. However it doesn't update in my UI, unless I reload it manually.

Right now, I'm using `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation` to dismiss the view after deletion completion.

Here's my Firebase code:

```
func deleteData(category: String,completion: @escaping (success) -> Void){
    db.collection("passwords").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").getDocument{(snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        let documentID = snapshot.data()!["date"] as! String
        db.collection("passwords").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").collection(documentID).document("\(category)").delete(){ err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                completion(false)
            } else {
                print("Document successfully removed!")
                completion(true)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

And here's the SwiftUI code:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
var body: some View {
    ForEach(self.data){item in
        HStack{
            Text(item.category)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                deleteData(category: item.category!){
                    (success) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        print("deleted successfully")
                        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                }
            }){
                Text("Delete")
            }
        }
            .onAppear{
                fetchData()
            }
    }

}
```

```
class FirebaseData: ObservableObject {
    @State var id: String?
    @State var category: String
    @State var password: String
    
    init(id: String?, password: String, category: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.password = password
        self.category = category
    }
}
```

`self.data` comes from `@State var data: [FirebaseData] = []`.

Comment: There's no way to debug this unless you show the relevant code.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to save the code after editing, its up now :)

Comment: The relevant code still isn’t there. What populates self.data? It doesn’t get manipulated in deleteData, so it’s reasonable that it wouldn’t be updating.

Comment: data is a Firebase class, which is retrieved from Firestore. And yes deleteData deletes that particular data from firestore, but it doesn't update on the UI, unless I manually refresh it

Comment: You aren’t showing where self.data gets set or manipulated, so this is impossible to debug.

Comment: I don't understand how self.data is relevant, but I have added the edit above, its a mere struct, that is used to push the data into firestore database, and is retrieved from firestore.

Comment: You are asking why your UI doesn’t update. The UI you have shown is entirely based on the contents of self.data. You still haven’t shown any code that sets or updates that value. Sorry, it is not possible to debug without that information. Good luck.

Comment: It's a ForEach List, that on appear fetches data from Firestore. That's how the data is loaded. And when I delete a value from the loaded data, my UI doesn't update. I have literally given all of my code above. I still don't understand what all you need? I've attached a codeshare link to my entire code here: https://codeshare.io/N3omq9

Comment: I needed `fetchData`, which is where you set the value of `self.data` -- now that you've provided that, I can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. In general, when doing asynchronous work, you probably want to do them in an `ObservableObject`, and not in the `View` itself -- I've moved the code into a view model.
2. Your model shouldn't be an `ObservableObject` -- it should just be a struct. Using `@State` on an `ObservableObject` doesn't do anything anyways -- use `@Published` values when using `ObservableObject`
3. You're using `getDocument` which gets the data *once*, which is why your UI isn't updating. If you want the UI to update, use snapshot listeners: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

```
struct FirebaseData {
    var id: String?
    var category: String
    var password: String
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var data : [FirebaseData] = []
    private let db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listener : ListenerRegistration?
    
    func fetchData(){
        db.collection("passwords").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
            .getDocument{(snapshot, error) in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                let documentID = snapshot.data()!["date"] as! String
                
                self.listener = self.db.collection("passwords").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").collection(documentID)
                    .addSnapshotListener(){ (querySnapshot, err) in //<-- Here
                        if let err = err {
                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                        } else {
                            self.data = (querySnapshot?.documents ?? []).map {
                                FirebaseData(id: $0.documentID,
                                             category: $0.data()["category"] as? String ?? "",
                                             password: $0.data()["password"] as? String ?? "")
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
    
    func deleteData(category: String,completion: @escaping (success) -> Void){
        db.collection("passwords").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").getDocument{(snapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            let documentID = snapshot.data()!["date"] as! String
            self.db.collection("passwords").document("\(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)").collection(documentID).document("\(category)").delete(){ err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                    completion(false)
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully removed!")
                    completion(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ForEach(viewModel.data, id: \.self.id) { item in
                HStack{
                    Text(item.category)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        viewModel.deleteData(category: item.category){
                            (success) -> Void in
                            if success {
                                print("deleted successfully")
                            }
                        }
                    }){
                        Text("Delete")
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear{
                viewModel.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's some more refactoring I'd do, such as:

1. Make sure you're not using `!` anywhere to force unwrap -- this can cause crashes
2. Store the document ID so that you're not doing another query inside `deleteData`

But, this should get you started for now.